# I am having some difficulties with an awk statement in my bash code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to check if certain values (DIC, IC, RNDIC) are in a text file's first row but not in the first column. Sew below for all the detail. Not that each field in the text file is tabulated.

file.txt

```
NO   DIC   IC   RNDIC   FI   BO   CF
---
1    2    3    4    5    6
```

This is the code I have to deal with this file:

```
type=$(awk 'NR==1 {
   for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) 
   {
      if (i != 1 && ($i == "DIC" || $i == "IC" || $i == "RNDIC")) 
         print "1"   
   }  
}' $PWD/file.txt)

if [[ $type == "1" ]]; then
   # rest of the code is irrelevant
fi

echo $type
```

The problem is that it never enters the `if` statement after `$type` is initialized. The reason is because `$type` is actually `1 1` instead of `1`. I realize the mistake I made is with the `if` statment in the `for` loop but don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `exit` after printing `1` once:

```
type=$(awk 'NR==1 {
   for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      if (i != 1 && ($i == "DIC" || $i == "IC" || $i == "RNDIC")) {
         print "1"
         exit
      }
   }  
}' $PWD/file.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to fork and rely on awk if you're using bash:

```
read -ra FIELDS < "$PWD/file.txt"
for A in "${FIELDS[@]:1}"; do
    case "$A" in
    DIC|IC|RNDIC)
        # <do some things>
        break
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Or

```
function is_type1 {
    local FIELDS A
    read -ra FIELDS < "$1"
    for A in "${FIELDS[@]:1}"; do
        case "$A" in
        DIC|IC|RNDIC)
            return 0
            ;;
        esac
    done
    return 1
}

if is_type1 "$PWD/file.txt"; then
    # <do some things>
fi
```

Note: I just used `case` since I don't know the version of bash and `extglob` may be a hassle.